# What is the LINQ way to implode/join a string array?

Tags: .net, linq, string

I have the following string array:

```
var sa = new string[] {"yabba","dabba","doo"};
```

I can convert it to "yabba, dabba, doo" it using string.Join() but what is the super-cool LINQ way of doing it?  The Join extension method seems promising but for a novice like me very confusing.