# Using LINQ to concatenate strings

Tags: c#, linq, string-concatenation

What is the most efficient way to write the old-school:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (strings.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (string s in strings)
    {
        sb.Append(s + ", ");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

...in LINQ?

Comment: Did you discover any other super cool LINQ ways of doing things?

Comment: Well the selected answer and all the other options don't work in Linq to Entities.

Comment: @Binoj Antony, don't make your database do string concatenation.

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX: Because it can't and because it shouldn't. I don't know about other databases but in SQL Server you can only concat (n)varcahr which limits you to (n)varchar(max). It shouldn't because business logic shouldn't be implemented in the data layer.

Comment: None of the answers work with the EntityFramework - see the comment I placed below the marked answer.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: If anyone does do this old school way, you could replace sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2); with sb.Length -= 2;

Comment: I was using: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); AttachmentsStringList.Select(a => sb.Append(a + ",")); return sb.ToString();   I search for this to see if there was a better way. I haven't tested that yet.

Answer (score 581, accepted):

**This answer shows usage of LINQ (`Aggregate`) as requested in the question and is not intended for everyday use. Because this does not use a `StringBuilder` it will have horrible performance for very long sequences. For regular code use `String.Join` as shown in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218419/477420)**

Use aggregate queries like this:

```
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
var res = words.Aggregate(
   "", // start with empty string to handle empty list case.
   (current, next) => current + ", " + next);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

This outputs:

```
, one, two, three
```

An aggregate is a function that takes a collection of values and returns a scalar value. Examples from T-SQL include min, max, and sum. Both VB and C# have support for aggregates. Both VB and C# support aggregates as extension methods. Using the dot-notation, one simply calls a method on an [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) object.

Remember that aggregate queries are executed immediately.

More information - [MSDN: Aggregate Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/aggregate-queries)

---

If you really want to use `Aggregate` use variant using `StringBuilder` proposed in comment by [CodeMonkeyKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78830/codemonkeyking) which would be about the same code as regular `String.Join` including good performance for large number of objects:

```
 var res = words.Aggregate(
     new StringBuilder(), 
     (current, next) => current.Append(current.Length == 0? "" : ", ").Append(next))
     .ToString();
```

Comment: The first example doesn't output "one, two, three", it outputs ", one, two, three" (Notice the leading comma).

Comment: In your first example, since you seed with `""`, the first value used in `current` is an empty string. So, for 1 or more element, you'll always get `, ` at the start of the string.

Comment: @Mort I have fixed this

Answer (score 438):

```
return string.Join(", ", strings.ToArray());
```

---

In .Net 4, there's a new [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) for `string.Join` that accepts `IEnumerable<string>`.  The code would then look like:

```
return string.Join(", ", strings);
```

Comment: OK, so the solution doesn't use Linq, but it seems to work pretty well to me

Comment: This is the most correct answer.  It is faster than both the question and the accepted answer and is much clearer than Aggregate, which requires a paragraph-long explanation every time it is used.

Answer (score 137):

Why use Linq?

```
string[] s = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", s));
```

That works perfectly and accepts any `IEnumerable<string>` as far as I remember.  No need `Aggregate` anything here which is a lot slower.

Comment: .NET 4.0 has an IEnumerable<string> and IEnumrable<T> overload, which will make it much easier to use

Comment: As Cine points out, .NET 4.0 has the overload. Previous versions don't. You can still `String.Join(",", s.ToArray())` in the older versions though.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Comment: @Shog9 Merging makes answers here look like duplicated efforts, and the timestamps dont help at all.. Still the way to go.

Comment: @Armin: It could be useful if your source is streaming data instead of being a finite known size collection. Also, the streaming could be because the data comes in progressively. Then the LINQ solution could process data as it arrives instead of having to wait for the whole collection to be received. This way, if for instance only one value of a processed object is required, it is concatenated, the complex object is dropped and can then be recycled.

Answer (score 81):

Have you looked at the Aggregate extension method?

```
var sa = (new[] { "yabba", "dabba", "doo" }).Aggregate((a,b) => a + "," + b);
```

Comment: That's probably slower than String.Join(), and harder to read in code. Does answer the question for a "LINQ way", though :-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to taint the answer with my opinions. :P

Comment: It's unquestionably quite a bit slower, actually. Even using Aggregate with a StringBuilder instead of concatenation is slower than String.Join.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for - helped me understand Aggregate and the sort of things it's used for.

Comment: Made a test with 10.000.000 iterations, aggregate took 4.3 secs and string.join took 2.3 secs. So I would say the perf diff is unimportant for 99% of common use cases. So if you're already doing a lot of linq to process your data, there's usually no need to break that nice syntax and use string.join imo. https://gist.github.com/joeriks/5791981

Comment: @joeriks Did you do the tests with this crude implementation, or with a StringBuilder seed one?

Comment: Re : Performance of the `String.Join` vs folding with `Aggregate` : http://devlifeasis.blogspot.com/2012/10/stringjoin-vs-linqaggregate.html

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 61):

Real example from my code:

```
return selected.Select(query => query.Name).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

A query is an object that has a Name property which is a string, and I want the names of all the queries on the selected list, separated by commas.

Comment: Given the comments about performance, I should add that the example is from code that runs once when a dialog closes, and the list is unlikely to ever have more than about ten strings on it!

Comment: Any clue how to do this same task in Linq to Entities?

Comment: Excellent example.  Thank you for putting this into a real world scenario.  I had the same exact situation, with a property of an object that needed concating.

Comment: Upvoted for helping me figure out that first part of selecting the string property of my List<T>

Comment: Please write about performance of this approaching with larger array.

Answer (score 34):

Here is the combined Join/Linq approach I settled on after looking at the other answers and the issues addressed [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680156/957950) (namely that Aggregate and Concatenate fail with 0 elements).

`string Result = String.Join(",", split.Select(s => s.Name));`

or (if `s` is not a string)

`string Result = String.Join(",", split.Select(s => s.ToString()));`

- Simple
- easy to read and understand
- works for generic elements
- allows using objects or object properties
- handles the case of 0-length elements
- could be used with additional Linq filtering
- performs well (at least in my experience)
- doesn't require (manual) creation of an additional object (e.g. `StringBuilder`) to implement

And of course Join takes care of the pesky final comma that sometimes sneaks into other approaches (`for`, `foreach`), which is why I was looking for a Linq solution in the first place.

Comment: miss-matched parenthesis.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Comment: I like this answer because using `.Select()` like this provides an easy place to modify each element during this operation. For example, wrapping each item in some character like so `string Result = String.Join(",", split.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));`

Answer (score 29):

You can use `StringBuilder` in `Aggregate`:

```
  List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };

  StringBuilder sb = strings
    .Select(s => s)
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (ag, n) => ag.Append(n).Append(", "));

  if (sb.Length > 0) { sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2); }

  Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

(The `Select` is in there just to show you can do more LINQ stuff.)

Comment: +1 nice. However, IMO it's better to avoid adding the extra "," than to erase it afterward. Something like `new[] {"one", "two", "three"}.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) =>{if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(", ");sb.Append(s);return sb;}).ToString();`

Comment: You would save precious clock cycles by not checking the `if (length > 0)` in the linq and by taking it out.

Comment: I agree with dss539.  My version is along the lines of `new[] {"", "one", "two", "three"}.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString())) ? sb.Append(s) : sb.Append(", ").Append(s)).ToString();`

Comment: @ProfNimrod, Your code turns the StringBuffer into a string on every iteration (`sb.ToString()`). (It also checks for null something that could never be null.) You completely lose the advantage of the StringBuffer, and it’s as bad as just concatenating strings.

Answer (score 22):

quick performance data for the StringBuilder vs Select & Aggregate case over 3000 elements:

Unit test - Duration (seconds)
LINQ_StringBuilder - 0.0036644
LINQ_Select.Aggregate - 1.8012535

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void LINQ_StringBuilder()
    {
        IList<int> ints = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000;i++ )
        {
            ints.Add(i);
        }
        StringBuilder idString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int id in ints)
        {
            idString.Append(id + ", ");
        }
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void LINQ_SELECT()
    {
        IList<int> ints = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            ints.Add(i);
        }
        string ids = ints.Select(query => query.ToString())
                         .Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
    }
```

Comment: Helpful in deciding to go the non LINQ route for this

Comment: The time difference is probably StringBuilder vs String Concatination using +.  Nothing to do with LINQ or Aggregate.  Put StringBuilder into LINQ Aggregate (plenty of examples on SO), and it should be just as fast.

Answer (score 21):

I always use the extension method:

```
public static string JoinAsString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, string seperator)
{
    var ar = input.Select(i => i.ToString());
    return string.Join(seperator, ar);
}
```

Comment: `string.Join` in .net 4 can already take an `IEnumerable<T>` for any arbitrary `T`.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 14):

By '*super-cool LINQ way*' you might be talking about the way that LINQ makes functional programming a lot more palatable with the use of extension methods. I mean, the syntactic sugar that allows functions to be chained in a visually linear way (one after the other) instead of nesting (one inside the other). For example:

```
int totalEven = Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Where(myInts, i => i % 2 == 0));
```

can be written like this:

```
int totalEven = myInts.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Sum();
```

You can see how the second example is easier to read. You can also see how more functions can be added with less of the indentation problems or the *Lispy* closing parens appearing at the end of the expression.

A lot of the other answers state that the `String.Join` is the way to go because it is the fastest or simplest to read. But if you take my interpretation of '*super-cool LINQ way*' then the answer is to use `String.Join` but have it wrapped in a LINQ style extension method that will allow you to chain your functions in a visually pleasing way. So if you want to write `sa.Concatenate(", ")` you just need to create something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableStringExtensions
{
   public static string Concatenate(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator)
   {
      return String.Join(separator, strings);
   }
}
```

This will provide code that is as performant as the direct call (at least in terms of algorithm complexity) and in some cases may make the code more readable (depending on the context) especially if other code in the block is using the chained function style.

Comment: The number of typos in this thread is crazy: seperator => separator, Concatinate => Concatenate

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 5):

Here it is using pure LINQ as a single expression:

```
static string StringJoin(string sep, IEnumerable<string> strings) {
  return strings
    .Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(
       new StringBuilder().Append(strings.FirstOrDefault() ?? ""), 
       (sb, x) => sb.Append(sep).Append(x));
}
```

And its pretty damn fast!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to cheat a little and throw out a new answer to this that seems to sum up the best of everything on here instead of sticking it inside of a comment.

So you can one line this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };

string concat = strings        
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder("\a"), 
                    (current, next) => current.Append(", ").Append(next))
    .ToString()
    .Replace("\a, ",string.Empty);
```

**Edit:** You'll either want to check for an empty enumerable first or add an `.Replace("\a",string.Empty);` to the end of the expression. Guess I might have been trying to get a little too smart.

The answer from @a.friend might be slightly more performant, I'm not sure what Replace does under the hood compared to Remove. The only other caveat if some reason you wanted to concat strings that ended in \a's you would lose your separators... I find that unlikely. If that is the case you do have [other fancy characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx) to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of choices here. You can use LINQ and a StringBuilder so you get the performance too like so:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
List<string> MyList = new List<string>() {"one","two","three"};

MyList.ForEach(w => builder.Append(builder.Length > 0 ? ", " + w : w));
return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: It would be faster to not check the `builder.Length > 0` in the ForEach and by removing the first comma after the ForEach

Answer (score 2):

You can combine LINQ and `string.join()` quite effectively. Here I am removing an item from a string. There are better ways of doing this too but here it is:

```
filterset = String.Join(",",
                        filterset.Split(',')
                                 .Where(f => mycomplicatedMatch(f,paramToMatch))
                       );
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 1):

I did the following quick and dirty when parsing an IIS log file using linq, it worked @ 1 million lines pretty well (15 seconds), although got an out of memory error when trying 2 millions lines.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " entering main");

        // USED THIS DOS COMMAND TO GET ALL THE DAILY FILES INTO A SINGLE FILE: copy *.log target.log 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Log File Analysis\12-8 E5.log");

        Debug.WriteLine(lines.Count().ToString());

        string[] a = lines.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("#Software:") &&
                                      !x.StartsWith("#Version:") &&
                                      !x.StartsWith("#Date:") &&
                                      !x.StartsWith("#Fields:") &&
                                      !x.Contains("_vti_") &&
                                      !x.Contains("/c$") &&
                                      !x.Contains("/favicon.ico") &&
                                      !x.Contains("/ - 80")
                                 ).ToArray();

        Debug.WriteLine(a.Count().ToString());

        string[] b = a
                    .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
                    .Select(words => string.Join(",", words))
                    .ToArray()
                    ;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Log File Analysis\12-8 E5.csv", b);

        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " leaving main");

    }
```

The real reason I used linq was for a Distinct() I neede previously:

```
string[] b = a
    .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
    .Where(l => l.Length > 11)
    .Select(words => string.Format("{0},{1}",
        words[6].ToUpper(), // virtual dir / service
        words[10]) // client ip
    ).Distinct().ToArray()
    ;
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about this a while ago, what I did seams to be exactly what you're looking for:

http://ondevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/string-concatenation-made-easy.html

In the blog post describe how to implement extension methods that works on IEnumerable and are named Concatenate, this will let you write things like:

```
var sequence = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
string result = sequence.Concatenate();
```

Or more elaborate things like:

```
var methodNames = typeof(IFoo).GetMethods().Select(x => x.Name);
string result = methodNames.Concatenate(", ");
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I benchmarked `string.Join` vs `.Aggregate` on a string array of 15 strings using BDN:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| String_Join | 92.99 ns | 9.905 ns | 0.543 ns | 0.0560 | 352 B |
| LING_Aggregate | 406.00 ns | 74.662 ns | 4.092 ns | 0.4640 | 2912 B |

The gap increases with bigger arrays