# Join together all items of a list in an output string in .NET

Tags: c#, linq, string, .net-3.5

How can I write a LINQ expression (or anything else) that selects an item from a List and join them together?

#### Example

```
IList<string> data = new List<string>();

data.Add("MyData1");
data.Add("MyData2");

string result = // Some LINQ query... I try data.Select(x => x + ",");

//result = "MyData1, MyData2"
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Just go with ([String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(VS.71).aspx)):

```
string joined = String.Join(",", data.ToArray());
```

But if it has to be LINQ, you could try:

```
string joinedLinq = data.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j);
```

Comment: String.Join was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Melurus, also note that new in .NET 4, the call to .ToArray() is not necessary, nor does it need to be a collection of strings. string.Join has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: For those stumbling across this now: I settled on a modified version of this (`Select` instead of `Aggregate`) to avoid the issue with 0 elements or calling `ToArray`; full answer is on a more viewed (easier to find) question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734070/957950

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: `String.Join<T>(delimiter, IEnumerable<T>)` is the best solution for me!

Answer (score 15):

You may be tempted to use Aggregate() if you're sticking with LINQ:

```
IList<int> data = new List<int>();

data.Add(123);
data.Add(456);

var result = data.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a,b) => a + "," + b);
```

**I wouldn't recommend this** because as I found out the hard way this will fail if the list contains zero items - or was it if it had only one item. I forget, but it fails all the same :-)

```
String.Join(...) is the best way
```

In the example above, where the datatype is *not* a string, you can do this:

```
string.Join(",", data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: It will throw if the enumerable has no elements. Check for count == 0.

Comment: As Anthony Pegram wrote `String.Join<T>(delimiter, IEnumerable<T>)` is the best solution in .NET 4!

Answer (score 3):

As Anthony Pegram wrote `String.Join<T>(delimiter, IEnumerable<T>)` is the best solution in .NET 4!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Aggregate() when you need to join a list into a single aggregated object.

```
string s = "";
if(data.Count > 0)
  s = data.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ',' + b);
```