# fastest way to Copy the Array Of String in to another string value in c#

Tags: c#, copy

I want to put an array of strings to a string value. What is the fastest way to copy `mm` to `k`?

```
string[] mm = new string[1,000,000]; // its just sample
string k = "";
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what "put them to string value" means a bit more? Concatenate? Join with separator?

Comment: Your declaration/definition of `mm` is not C#!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert string array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841401/convert-string-array-to-string)

Comment: [`string k = string.Concat(mm);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: or [`string k = string.Join(", ", mm); // if you want readability`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of `mm` changes to something like this ...

```
string[] mm = {"Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"};
```

... you can concatenate all strings of the array `mm` into one string using the [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.Concat);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method such as like this:

```
string k = System.String.Concat(mm);
```

It is possible that there is a faster way, but this is a convenient way to use an existing .NET Framework method which is already very well optimized.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string k = String.Join("",mm)`
```

Use  the `String.Join` method which accepts the array and a delimiter

BTW, your array does not have string values

If you do not need any spaces/separators between the parts you can use `String.Concat` which accepts a list of strings

```
string k = String.Concat(mm)
```

Comment: The `Join()` method starts with a delimiter, not the array. Also, the PO wasn't asking for adding delimiters in between the strings. Use `Concat()`!

Comment: its the delimiter returning a  comma separated list. If you want no spaces then do it with an empty `''`

Comment: See my answer. There's also a link to the MSDN so that you read more background about `Concat()`.