# C#/LINQ: Concatenating strings

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Is there a better—more functional, succinct, or elegant—way to write this? A reduce/fold function, perhaps?

```
var key = String.Join(String.Empty,
    new[] {
        keyRoot,
        controllerName,
        actionName
    }.Concat(
        from param in params
        select param.Key + param.Value
    )
);
```

The input is a few variables that are strings, as well as an enumerable of concatenated keys/values from a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

The output should be all of these strings concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could use the LINQ Aggregate function:

[Using LINQ to concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings)

Comment: Just to be clear: Aggregate is, in fact, a variety of the reduce/fold functions mentioned in the question.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that the variables `keyRoot`, `controllerName`, and `actionName` are not in the same enumerable as the dictionary, so you'd still have to use a concat.

Answer (score 1):

More readable to me would be something like this:

```
string key = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
                            keyRoot, 
                            controllerName, 
                            actionName, 
                            string.Join(string.Empty, parameters.Select( p =>  p.Key + p.Value)));
```

This might not be as "functional" but certainly as succinct and clear as I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't improve it much...

```
var key = string.Concat(
   new[] {
    keyRoot,
    controllerName,
    actionName
   }.Concat(
       params.Select(kvp) => param.Key + param.Value)
   ).ToArray ()
);
```

This is 2 lines shorter if it doesn't have to be a single statement.

```
var list = new List<String> {
    keyRoot,
    controllerName,
    actionName
   };
list.AddRange (params.Select(kvp) => param.Key + param.Value));
var key = string.Concat(list.ToArray ());
```

Answer (score 0):

With an extension to `StringBuilder`:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions {

  public static StringBuilder AppendAll(this StringBuilder builder, IEnumerable<string> strings) {
    foreach (string s in strings) builder.Append(s);
    return builder;
  }

}
```

it gets rather short and efficient:

```
string key =
  new StringBuilder()
  .Append(keyRoot)
  .Append(controllerName)
  .Append(actionName)
  .AppendAll(parameters.Select(p => p.Key + p.Value))
  .ToString();
```

This will build the string without creating any intermediate arrays.

One thing to improve would be to avoid the intermittent strings `p.Key + p.Value` by adding the key and value directly to the `StringBuilder`, but then the code gets less reusable.

Another thing to improve would be to set the capacity of the `StringBuilder`, but then you would need to loop though the dictionary and add upp the length of the strings first.

(Note: I used `parameters` for the name of the dictionary instead of `params`, as that is a keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

I think for concatenating the sequence of all strings, your construct is already as functional as you can get.

Instead of using `String.Join` with an empty string, I'd probably use a `StringBuilder` together with a `ForEach` extenstion method like

```
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static void ForEach(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action) {
    foreach (var entry in enumerable)
      action(entry);
  }
}
```

I also would define a local variable for the sequence like

```
var seq = new[] {
                   keyRoot,
                   controllerName,
                   actionName
          }.Concat(
           from param in params select param.Key + param.Value
          );
var sb = new StringBuilder();
seq.ForEach(s=>sb.Append(s));
```

Of course, using the `Aggregate` function would be more "functional", but it is not more readable in my opinion plus it has performance penalties, because you need to construct intermediate strings...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in one expressions using `Aggregate` (effectively a fold):

```
var key = params.Aggregate(new StringBuilder()
    .Append(keyRoot)
    .Append(controllerName)
    .Append(actionName),
    (sb, p) => sb.Append(p.Key).Append(p.Value))
    .ToString();
```