# C# convert DOMAIN\USER to USER@DOMAIN

Tags: c#

I currently have the following code:

```
string user = @"DOMAIN\USER";
string[] parts = user.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string user = parts[1] + "@" + parts[0];
```

Input string `user` can be in one of two formats:

```
DOMAIN\USER
DOMAIN\\USER (with a double slash)
```

Whats the most elegant way in C# to convert either one of these strings to:

```
USER@DOMAIN
```

Comment: You could do it with a Regex. I'll leave someone else to construct that regex though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure you would call this most elegant:

```
string[] parts = user.Split(new string[] {"/"},
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string user = string.Format("{0}@{1}", parts[1], parts[0]);
```

Comment: @MAfifi - Not needed, not with `RemoveEmptyEntries`. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
        string user = @"DOMAIN//USER";
        Regex pattern = new Regex("[/]+");
        var sp = pattern.Split(user);
        user = sp[1] + "@" + sp[0];
        Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Comment: Agh, that'll teach me from thinking I understand regexes for a while. +1

Answer (score 2):

A variation on Oded's answer might use [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx):

```
string[] parts = user.Split(new string[] {"/"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Array.Reverse(parts);
return String.Join("@",parts);
```

Alternatively, could use linq (based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings)):

```
return user.Split(new string[] {"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Aggregate((current, next) => next + "@" + current);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
String[] parts = user.Split(new String[] {@"\", @"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
user = String.Format("{0}@{1}", parts[1], parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of adding another option, here it is:

```
string user = @"DOMAIN//USER";
string result = user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf("/")) + "@" + user.Substring(user.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, user.Length - (user.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```