# SELECT DISTINCT Query to string list

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

How can I covert single column from SELECT DISTINCT Query into a string with list of query results separated by commas.

My SQL Query example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName FROM CompanyA WHERE DIV_Num in ('SUB.EAST', 'SUB2', 'SUB3', 'HR.SUB', 'HR.SUB2')
```

Output example:

```
Bob
Alice
Jim
```

I would like to have result in single string:

```
Bob, Alice, Jim
```

Comment: You've tagged as asp.net and SQL server.  Do you need an answer in T-SQL, or can this be done in C# on the server side?  String manipulation like this is not SQL server's strong point - prob better done in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/218419/8155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Example

```
Select distinct ST2.SubjectID, 
           substring((Select ','+ST1.StudentName  AS [text()]
            From dbo.Students ST1
            Where ST1.SubjectID = ST2.SubjectID
            ORDER BY ST1.SubjectID
            For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) [Students]
     From dbo.Students ST2
```