# Group By repeats the same title twice

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, entity-framework-6.1

Given this Linq query to connect 3 tables just to retrieve the CategoryName I end up with the 2 categories but also with the same title twice. I suspect I need a group by to eliminate the duplicate title and keep the 2 categories.

```
From ca In be_Categories Join c In be_PostCategory On ca.CategoryID Equals (c.CategoryID) 
Join p1 In be_Posts On c.PostID Equals (p1.PostID) Where p1.PostRowID = 1002
Select ca.CategoryName, p1.title
```

I have test the query in LinqPad and this is what I get:
[image]

I suspect I need a Group By to get the query working right so i can return the 2 categories but just one of everything else. I've been reading various resources on Group By but am no closer to getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the query and the results it looks like there is 2 Categories that meet the filter criteria, Group By will not make them go away, you might be missing a join which might filter out one, but most likely you need more filter criteria to eliminate one of the Category names

Here's a link that might help you do it in one query the .Aggregate()

[Using LINQ to concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to get both categories while still getting a single title etc. Any other way to filter it down to 1 title and 2 categories?

Comment: How do you expect the data to look?  If a title fit into 10 categories, you'd get 10 rows back each paired with the title. Do you want all the categories concatenated together for one line returned?

Comment: Yes - all the categories for a single title.

Comment: I would take your current result set and manipulate it to how you want the data to look before returning it.  I'm sure there is a way to 'continue' the query to make it in one but I don't have anything close to be able to start playing with it to get it right.

Comment: added a link that I think will help.