# How to combine value os list object in to a single string seperated by comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having list of skills on my Registration page like:

**playing,Dancing,Programming etc**.

```
 public partial class EmployeeMaster
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Skills { get; set; }
 }
```

Now on my post method i am receiving Skills like this:

This skill is a list object:listSkill object:

```
[0]:Name=Playing
   Selected=true

[1]:Name=Dancing
   Selected=true

[2]:Name=Programming
   Selected=false

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EmployeeModel m)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var employeeModel = new EmployeeMaster();
            employeeModel.Skills = m.Skills.Select(t => t.Name).SingleOrDefault();  //How to do this as this would take only single value not all skills?
```

I want to concatinate all this skills in to a single string seperated by comma and store in my database table.

Comment: Please update your code to the latest, because you say List of Skills, but it is a string.

Comment: You want to concatenate all skills to a single string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by using `string.Join` with your desired `Skills` property (`Name` in this case):

```
employeeModel.Skills = string.Join(", ", m.Skills.Select(t => t.Name));
```

This will concatenate all your skill names using the `", "` separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
employeeModel.Skills = string.Join(",", m.Skills.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToList());
```

my suggestion use like this very helpful to you.