# How can I get a comma separated list of values from a List using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of phrases:  `List<Phrase>` where the Phrase object has a property of `PhraseId`. What I need to do is to get a string that consists of every Id enclosed in single quotes followed by a "," except for the last PhraseId?

In other words I would like to get a string looking something like this:

> 'id1','id2','id3'

I've seen the LINQ Select command but I think this just gives me another List.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
var result = string.Join(",", phrases.Select(x => $"'{x.PhraseId}'"));
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
>   string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
>   interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a
>   result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the
>   string representations of the expression results. This feature is
>   available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.