# Convert List Combo into Comma-Separated String in c#

Tags: c#, list

My code is as below:

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string>();

....

sCombo = reader["Combo"].ToString();
colorList.Add(sCombo.ToString());

....


foreach (var Combo in colorList)
{
   Response.Write(string.Join(",", Combo));
}
```

Output: `D410D430D440D420` instead of `D410,D430,D440,D420`

What is the most simple way to convert the `List<string>` into a comma-separated string?

**EDIT #01**

Your suggestion working, but I need this new output :

```
'D410','D430','D440','D420'
```

Because use this `string` on sql query.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would be very handy

```
var colorList = new List<string>() { "D410", "D430", "D440", "D420" };
string commaSeparated = string.Join(",", colorList);                      
Console.WriteLine(commaSeparated);
```

or try solution based on Linq

```
Console.WriteLine(colorList.Select(s => s + ",").Aggregate((s, q) => s + q).TrimEnd(','));
```

The output

```
D410,D430,D440,D420
```

**Edit**

```
string result = string.Join(",", colorList.Select(e => "'" + e + "'"));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

will give you

```
'D410','D430','D440','D420'
```

Answer (score 4):

Without a `foreach`:

```
Response.Write(string.Join(",", colorList));
```

Comment: Your suggestion working, but I need this new output : 

    'D410','D430','D440','D420' 

Because use this `string` on sql query.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to output like this => `'D410','D430','D440','D420'`

So try below,

```
string result = string.Join(",", colorList.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
Response.Write(result);
```

**What we did above?**

**Answer:** First we flatten each item in your list with a single quoted (`''`) surrounding string and then we just pass this newly generated flatten result to join method of string with a comma (`,`) to get your desired output.

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]