# How do I use LINQ to reduce a collection of strings to one delimited string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings and I want to dump them out as a string with semi-colon delimiters.

```cs
IEnumerable<string> foo = from f in fooList
                          where f.property == "bar"
                          select f.title;
```

I now want to output this:

```
title1;title2;title3;title4
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122670/what-is-the-linq-way-to-implode-join-a-string-array

Comment: Not sure why you need to use linq to perform that...just use string.join like suggested.

Comment: @Rig he probably expected a built-in reduce method, because most functional languages come with it. And indeed Aggregate is LINQ's reduce implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string result = string.Join(";", fooList.Where(x=>x.property == "bar").Select(x=>x.title));
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

Comment: +1: first in, not as detailed, but still pipped 'em at the post.

Comment: Thanks. With a quick response, you can't always be detailed :)

Comment: True, but you can edit it for up to 2 minutes afterwards, before it even says "edited" :)

Answer (score 15):

Using LINQ instead of String.Join as that was what was asked for. Though really `String.Join` is probably a safer / easier bet.

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = from f in fooList
                      where f.property == "bar"
                      select f.title;
string join = foo.Aggregate((s, n) => s + ";" + n);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for: the LINQ-version of reduce.

Answer (score 6):

Since .NET 2.0, the string class provides a convenient [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method. While it originally operated on arrays only, .NET 4 adds an IEnumerable overload...

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = from f in fooList
                          where f.property == "bar"
                          select f.title;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", foo));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this particular overload (taking an `IEnumerable` as parameter) was only added in .NET 4